# Flex mobile HTTPMultiService set user-agent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I'm developing a Flex mobile application and I'm using the Http Services within FlashBuilder (4.7) to send/receive data. I'm having some issues with how the server is setup to accept calls (from the mobile platform) and apparently setting the User-Agent in Android works just fine. But I can't seem to be able to find a way to set the User-Agent in FlashBuilder.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: are you able to access this service from browser? FYI, if you want to send data to service then you can use POST and GET method.

Comment: Hi. It works perfectly from any browsers I've tried be that GET or POST the php works perfectly. I get a 500 error if I try it from a mobile platform

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the traffic between the client and server with a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark?  You can't set the User-Agent header in Flex, but I suspect you may have a different problem with request formatting here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest('URL_OF_YOUR_SERVICE');
            var userCredential:Object = new Object();
            userCredential['user_email'] = 'YOUR_MAIL';
            userCredential['user_password'] = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';

            request.data=JSON.stringify(userCredential);// use this if your service accept json only else give Object directly
            request.method = 'post';// specify here method GET or POST
            var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, userLoginCompleteHandler);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOErrorHanlder);
            try
            {
                loader.load(request);
            }
            catch(error:Error)
            {
                trace("Login Error:: "+ error.toString());
            }
```

may this will help you, here i have defined `userLoginCompleteHandler` and `onIOErrorHanlder` event listner for result and fault.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't set the `User-Agent` header in Flex.

From [this Adobe forums post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/19620):

> Note again that since the underlying Flash API is flash.net.URLLoader there are certain headers that
> you cannot send. For details, please see the docs for flash.net.URLRequestHeader.

The [URLRequestHeader docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html) say:

> In Flash Player and in Adobe AIR content outside of the application
> security sandbox, the following request headers cannot be used:
>
> ... User-Agent, ...